# Compose checkers

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a checkers game on jetpack compose kotlin, but I'm suffering with the problem that the result is not displayed on the screen. That is, the checker moves in the logs, but not on the screen.

```
enum class Piece {
    EMPTY,
    BLACK,
    WHITE
}

@Composable
fun CheckersScreen(navHostController: NavHostController) {

    val context = LocalContext.current


    var selectedChecker by remember { mutableStateOf<Pair<Int, Int>?>(null) }

    val board = remember { mutableStateOf(Array(8) { Array(8) { Piece.EMPTY } }) }

    var localSelectedChecker by remember { mutableStateOf<Pair<Int, Int>?>(null) }








    for (i in 0 until 3) {
        for (j in 0 until 8) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 1) {
                board.value[i][j] = Piece.WHITE
            }
        }
    }

    for (i in 5 until 8) {
        for (j in 0 until 8) {
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 1) {
                board.value[i][j] = Piece.BLACK
            }
        }
    }



    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(bottom = 30.dp)
    ) {


        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 152.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 5.dp, end = 5.dp)
                .size(400.dp)
                .shadow(4.dp, shape = RectangleShape)
        ) {
            Column {
                for (row in 0 until 8) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                    ) {
                        for (column in 0 until 8) {
                            val color =
                                if ((row + column) % 2 == 0) Color.White else Color(139, 69, 19)

                            val isWhitePiece = board.value[row][column] == Piece.WHITE
                            val isBlackPiece = board.value[row][column] == Piece.BLACK


                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(50.dp)
                                    .background(color)
                                    .clickable {
                                        if (isBlackPiece) {
                                            localSelectedChecker = Pair(row, column)
                                        } else if (localSelectedChecker != null) {
                                            val (fromRow, fromColumn) = localSelectedChecker!!
                                            if (!isValidMove(
                                                    fromRow,
                                                    fromColumn,
                                                    row,
                                                    column,
                                                    board.value
                                                )
                                            ) {
                                                board.value[row][column] =
                                                    board.value[fromRow][fromColumn]
                                                board.value[fromRow][fromColumn] = Piece.EMPTY
                                                board.value[row][column] = Piece.BLACK
                                                localSelectedChecker = null
                                                Log.d(
                                                    "pizda",
                                                    "Board state: ${
                                                        board.value.joinToString("\n") {
                                                            it.joinToString(" ")
                                                        }
                                                    }"
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },

                                ) {
                                val isSelected = selectedChecker == Pair(row, column)
                                val checkerImage = when {
                                    isWhitePiece -> R.drawable.white_checker
                                    isBlackPiece -> R.drawable.black_checker
                                    else -> 0
                                }

                                if (checkerImage != 0) {
                                    Image(
                                        painter = painterResource(id = checkerImage),
                                        contentDescription = null,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .size(40.dp)
                                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                                            .then(
                                                if (isSelected) {
                                                    Modifier.border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                                                } else {
                                                    Modifier
                                                }
                                            )
                                    )
                                }

                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun isValidMove(
    fromRow: Int,
    fromColumn: Int,
    toRow: Int,
    toColumn: Int,
    board: Array<Array<Piece>>
): Boolean {
    val piece = board[fromRow][fromColumn]
    val targetPiece = board[toRow][toColumn]
    Log.d("pizda", "fromColumn $fromColumn")
    Log.d("pizda", "fromRow $fromRow")
    Log.d("pizda", "toRow $toRow")
    Log.d("pizda", "toColumn $toColumn")
    val rowDiff = kotlin.math.abs(fromRow - toRow)
    val colDiff = kotlin.math.abs(fromColumn - toColumn)
    if (rowDiff != 1 || colDiff != 1) {
        Log.d("pizda", "here")
        return false
    }

    if (targetPiece != Piece.EMPTY) {
        Log.d("pizda", "here1")
        return false
    }

    if (piece == Piece.BLACK && toRow <= fromRow) {
        Log.d("pizda", "here2")
        return false
    }

    if (piece == Piece.WHITE && toRow >= fromRow) {
        Log.d("pizda", "here3")
        return false
    }

    val rowDirection = if (toRow > fromRow) 1 else -1
    val colDirection = if (toColumn > fromColumn) 1 else -1

    val intermediateRow = fromRow + rowDirection
    val intermediateColumn = fromColumn + colDirection

    if (kotlin.math.abs(toRow - fromRow) == 2 && kotlin.math.abs(toColumn - fromColumn) == 2) {

        val middlePiece = board[intermediateRow][intermediateColumn]

        if (middlePiece == Piece.EMPTY || middlePiece == piece) {
            Log.d("pizda", "here4")
            return false
        }

        Log.d("pizda", "here5")
        return true
    }

    Log.d("pizda", "here6")
    return false
}
```

Comment: The `for` loops in `CheckersScreen` are resetting the board state every time it's recomposed.  You need to move your setup outside the Composable, or at least `remember` it.

Comment: @ryan-m Hi, do you mean the `for` loop in the `Box`?

Comment: I do not.  I mean the ones with `board.value[i][j] = Piece.WHITE` and `board.value[i][j] = Piece.BLACK` in the inner loop.

Comment: @RyanM  okay, I put this code in a separate function, but I still call it in composable!

Comment: That's still a problem unless you're avoiding (via `remember` or similar) it being re-run every time the Composable is recomposed.

Comment: @RyanM ha ha, it's hard to understand, sori. Maybe you could write what you mean? Through the code. Thank you in advance

Comment: I will add that when you re-enter the screen, the game really redraws, and the checkers go. So yes

Answer (score 0):

So a big part of your problem is that you're mixing state and UI.  Don't do that.  Your UI and @Composable function should not be writing any state.  It should be reading it, performing little to no logic based on it (and all of the logic it does do should be strictly display logic), and writes should happen due to callbacks in your state.  By combining the two you're causing problems both technically (your initialization code runs every draw, so every draw resets state) and at a logical level (you're not separating business logic from UI at all, which will turn your code into a hard to debug mess).

The entire point of this form of UI is to draw each frame entirely based on the state, and to separate the UI from any manipulation of state at all.  In doing so, you isolate the two parts of the codebase so they're independently testable.  You can test the UI by generating appropriate states, and you can test the business logic by generating appropriate callback functions.  This mix violates all of that.